# How to construct a Hamilton path from a complete directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a directed graph.

Any 2 vertices are adjacent. The edge connecting a pair of vertices may be uni-directional or bi-directional.

How do I find a Hamilton path?

Side notes:

- Wikipedia says "A strongly connected simple directed graph with n vertices is Hamiltonian if every vertex has a full degree greater than or equal to n." Therefore, a solution must exist in my problem.
- I understand that the general Hamilton path problem is NP-Complete. But it feels like this specific version should have a polynomial solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variant of insertion sort to construct a path in quadratic time. Given a path

```
v1 v2 ... vn-1
```

on a subset of vertices, consider how to insert `vn`. If `vn` has an arc to `v1`, then prepend `vn`. If `vn-1` has an arc to `vn`, then append `vn`. Otherwise, there exists by [Sperner's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_lemma) an index `i` such that `vn` has an arc from `vi` and an arc to `vi+1`. Insert it there.

Comment: I created question https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116092/how-complete-directed-graph-with-n-vertices-is-connected-to-the-n-dimensional-si that calls of the explanation of connection between n-dimensional simplex (and its triangulation) and the complete directed graph with n-vertices. This may explain how exactly Sperner's lemma can be applied.